# How do i open jpg as txt or doc with google drive API V3

Tags: c#

How do i open jpg as txt or doc with google drive API V3

I can go to google drive and upload a jpg then open uploaded jpg as doc and any text in image will be separated. I am trying to use google drive api v3 to replicate this operation (it appears like I have to use C#).

```
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
Name = "image.jpg"
};

FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"\\cbslnas1\houshare\IT\OCR\image.jpg", 
System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
request.Fields = "id";
request.Upload();
}
```

The above snippet after credential validation gets my image.jpg uploaded just fine.

However, I have not figured out what API instructions to use to get a google document from the jpg. Honestly, I would prefer to get it into a text/plain file.

The ultimate goal is to use google drive for a way to OCR a series of characters out of an image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting. Have you considered using a proper OCR API, such as Google's Cloud Vision API? Why do you want to use Google Drive?

Comment: I do not believe there would be any cost other than development to use google drive...get a jpg, upload to google drive (which I have already been successful doing), open as text, download text file, parse txt file (which I am already doing for other OCR scenarios). I am only grabbing one piece of data off the image.  I know I can manually open a jpg as document and it OCRs the text on image...so figured i could get a text file) but turning out to be more difficult. Just looking for API command to open file as some format and save it.

Comment: Chances are that the Google Drive API will not allow you to do that, or at least not officially. There's a number of OCR APIs out there, I'd recommend doing a bit more research. Good luck!